# Draw an image with 2 points on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

I have to points (x1, x2, y1, y2). How can I draw an image (it's like a rectangle of width 10 and height 100) on a canvas with starting point x1, y1 and rotation degree determined by slope of the line between that two points?

It's like I want to overlap this line with an image:

```
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.stroke();
```

And I tried like this:

```
slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(-Math.atan(slope));
ctx.drawImage(image, x1, y1);
ctx.restore();
```

But with no success.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say no success, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: The images and the lines are not overlapping. Even the angle of rotation is not the same.

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36vfdx27/77/

Comment: for more than 2 lines the images are messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ctx.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) will rotate the context around the canvas origin.

In order to rotate around the corner of the shape, you'll need to translate the context to that point.

```
var slope = (pt.y1 - pt.y2) / (pt.x1 - pt.x2);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(pt.x1, pt.y1);
ctx.rotate(Math.atan(slope));
// we've already moved to here, so we can draw at 0, 0
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```

This only works for positive slopes. It's possible to also account for negative slopes by inverting the rotation if the slope is negative.

```
var slopeIsNegative = slope < 0;
var offsetAngle = slopeIsNegative ? Math.PI : 0;
ctx.rotate(Math.atan(slope) + offsetAngle);
```

Comment: Ok, but it's a problem with lines with negative slope. http://jsfiddle.net/36vfdx27/79/

Comment: There's a problem with slopes between [-0.5,0]. Are upside down like I never added PI... I've putted var slopeIsNegative = slope <= -0.5 and all are ok now, but I think is not a great idea.

Comment: See if you can find the angle that you would need to offset by to correct it, then extend that if statement to cover the edge case.

Comment: @DanPrince: Use `Math.atan2` which accounts for angles in various quadrants while `Math.atan` does not.